# Elastic search 2.0 GreaterOrEquals NEST 2.0

Tags: elasticsearch, search, nest

I use this code to search with date in elastic search 1.0. But this does not work in 2.0

```
var dateQuery = Query<SchoolModel>.Bool(
                q => q.Should(p=>p.Range(r => r.OnField(f => f.schoolenddate).GreaterOrEquals(dateTime)))))
```

How can I convert this to elastic search 2.0

Comment: What is the client used NEST or JAVA?

Comment: @jaspreet chahal NEST 2.0 (I have updated the question)

Comment: instead of range can your try 
DateRange(c => c
    .Field(p => p.schoolenddate)
    .GreaterThanOrEquals(dateTime)
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sytanx in Nest 2.0

```
DateRange(c => c
    .Field(p => p.schoolenddate)
    .GreaterThanOrEquals(dateTime)
)
```

Link to [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/date-range-query-usage.html)

Latest version of elasticsearch is 7.*. So if you are upgrading better to get latest version